# Pandas Dataframe MultiIndex groupby with 2 levels including "all" for both levels

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with a jobtype and age_group as categorical variables and then F1 and F2 as numerical variables. Each row is a one person's reply to a questionnaire and I want to calculate mean values in each jobtype - age_group combination

```
jobtype   | age_group | F1 | F2
"office"  | "20-30"   | 1.2| 2.4
"hospital"| "40-50"   | 2.3| 5.4
...
```

I have calculated the mean values for each combination of jobtype and age_group by

```
data_means_by_jobtype_age_group = data.groupby(["jobtype", "age_group"]).mean()
```

The result is a MultiIndex Dataframe with each combination of jobtype and age_group in the index and the mean values of F1 and F2 like should be. But isn't there a neat way to include "all" and "all" in the combinations, that is "all ages without filtering for each jobtype" and "all jobtypes without filtering for each age group"?

I have now done this separately but combining and renaming indices seems like a lot of work should there be a neat way to do this in one groupby-statement:

```
data_means_by_jobtype = data.groupby(["jobtype"]).mean()
```

and vice versa

```
data_means_by_age_group = data.groupby(["age_group"]).mean()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think simplists is overwrite columns to same values `All` before aggregate `mean` and then join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = data.groupby(["jobtype", "age_group"]).mean()

df2 = data.assign(age_group='All').groupby(["jobtype", "age_group"]).mean()
df3 = data.assign(jobtype='All').groupby(["jobtype", "age_group"]).mean()

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to add I also need "All", "All" combination but that works the same way just creating df4 with data.assign(age_group='All', jobtype='All') and include to concat.